# Is there a Python class that could mock the behaviour of symlinks without creating the symlink?

Tags: python

I work with a class from a library, and this class accepts a filepath-like object but will not create the object unless the name respect a certain standard (say has a specific extension).

I have a file that I know has the right content, but not a standard filename (it's in the git-lfs database, so stored in a folder of the form `f"{file_hash[0:2]}/{file_hash[2:4]/{file_hash[4:]}"`. I would like to load an instance of the class from this file, and I could create a symlink using bash `ln -s` command (this works), but I wonder if there wouldn't be a pythonic way to create a virtual Filepath-like object that mocks a filename but whose content actually points to the non-standard filename (without actually creating the symlink).

for example :

```
from pathlib import Path
class VirtualSymlink(MaybeInheritFromPathLikeClass?):
    def __init__(self, path_to_virtual_symlink, path_to_real_file):
        ...

my_virtual_symlink = VirtualSymlink(
    path_to_virtual_symlink=Path('./fake_inexisting_path_with.extension'), 
    path_to_real_file=Path('/real/path/to/file_without_extension')
)
```